# Muxing only audio into MP4 ffmpeg failed

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp4, pcm

I am trying to write audio encoded packets into a MP4 container.I have followed this [sample code](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/muxing-example_8c-source.html) and instead of creating dummy frame, I am feeding real **G.711 PCMU** encoded frame into ffmpeg. The writing seems working and file size is increasing, but the mp4 is not playing using `ffplay` or in VLC player.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt PCM mu-law / G.711 mu-law is supported by MP4 container. Either change to a different container and/or use a different audio format.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! yes, I found it sometime ago - MP4 doesn't support PCM stream, either I have to use `avi` or `mov` or transcode the audio into another codec format like `aac`. Now my question is -  only setting `m_pOutputFmt->audio_codec != AV_CODEC_ID_AAC` should work with my remote PCM encoded data? Or I have to change container extension or transcode audio into AAC too?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Sir, Can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846650/avformat-write-header-return-error-code-when-trying-to-write-pcmu-encoded-frame ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G.711 PCM encoded data is not supported by `mp4` container. So I used `mov` multimedia container instead. And for `mp4`, I transcoded PCM into AAC which is supported by `mp4`. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats) for details.